# Android SDK Manager runs only by running android file

Tags: java, android, android-sdk-manager

I succeed running the **SDK Manager** by clicking the `android.bat` file.       But when running the **SDK Manager** file it is still flashes and won't run.

Does anyone have a solution to this strange behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the environment variable `ANDROID_SDK_HOME` with your SDK Location.